# Powershell gives Get-Content : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: powershell, out-of-memory

I am trying to read file of size 1 GB as bytes in powershell using below command,

$data = Get-Content -Encoding byte $filepath

It throws below error :
Get-Content : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Searched net and found that running below command fixes it however this is not working for me. 
set-item wsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 4096

Comment: I am using powershell version 2.0 and can not move to new version

Comment: What's the purpose of reading the file?  Does it all need to be resident in memory at once?

Comment: If all else fails, you can always invoke .NET classes from PowerShell: `[io.file]::openread()` will give you a `FileStream` that you can then read piecemeal instead of trying to slurp it into memory all at once. This is awkward to program around, but it's something. Also, `[io.file]::readallbytes()` is faster than `get-content`, though it probably won't help with the memory issue.

Comment: You need to run the `Set-Item ` Command as an administrator in order for it to work.

Beware of working with massive files in PowerShell though.  Things can get to be...quite slow.

Comment: If the file can be processed "piecemeal", and doesn't require being read into memory all at once, Get-Content with the proper -ReadCount setting can be both faster and easier to code than [io.file] methods.

Comment: I need to read the file and supply the byte blob to a REST based call, will reading it in chunks will do?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen and mjolinor. I got the direction from your comments, used filestreams to read data and copyto to write on another stream instead of reading the file at once. Thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

By default MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024MB
If you want to read large file say 1GB or greater than that,
You need to set MaxMemoryPerShellMB.

Use below code to set MaxMemoryPerShellMB-

```
    function setpsmem
    {
          $winrmstatus = (get-service WinRM).Status
         if ($winrmstatus -eq 'Running')
    {
        $currentpsmem = (Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB).value
        if ($currentpsmem -le 4096)
        {            
            Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 4096
            Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 4096
            Restart-Service winrm
            $currentmemory = (Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB).value
            Write-Host "Script assign $currentmemory[MB] of memory to PowerShell" -ForegroundColor Green
        } 
        else
        {
            $currentpsmem = (Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB) | Select-Object value
            Write-Host "Powrshell has $currentpsmem[MB] of memory." -ForegroundColor Green
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "WinRM services is not running on current host." -ForegroundColor Red
    }

} setpsmem
```

Try it.